# Eclipse Unable To Find Install Path Node Native

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse, debugging, protractor

I'm having the following issue debugging a sample javascript that interacts with an angular web application. What I'm trying to do is run the following demo script per the following url

http://www.protractortest.org/#/

when I execute via the command line "protractor conf.js" it works as expected everytime. I follow this guide

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Protractor

to execute via eclipse IDE

however I can never debug the test script via the IDE. Eclipse always throw the following error when I set the "Node.js install" path to be "Native Node.js"

"Cannot find node install path node-native Do you want to update Protractor preferences?"

My Protractor settings in eclipse are the following:

```
  Node.js install: Native Node.js
  Native path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  Node.js path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

which corresponds to the path where node is installed on my windows machine.

I had procmon running profiling when this popup appears and I spotted this oddity?

CreateFile|C:\Windows\System32\node-native|NAME NOT FOUND|Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a

I'm not sure why why node-native is going to the path? Would anyone would know how to resolve this issue i'm seeing so that I can debug a protractor script via Eclipse IDE?

```
**Btw the Eclipse IDE i'm using is**
```

Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

```
**Node Install**
```

v4.4.7 x64

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a new version of protractor (3.2 or greater), the path for cli.js has changed. Change the path from: `protractor/lib/cli.js` to `protractor/built/cli.js`

Comment: Yeah tried that...unfortunately that doesn't resolve the issue I'm facing

Comment: It's a bug of tern.java. I have fixed for 1.3.0. See https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/207 To use protractor you can use embed node.js for the moment or install 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site

Answer (score 0):

The solution is available here : https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/181

The solution is to install "Tern Debuggers". Run the conf.js file again with setting :  Run in debug mode with "Start node.js in only run mode". It should work now.

I installed the add-ons for eclipse from:
http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/