# Running Protractor in eclipse giving errors

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have installed protractor, but I am getting the below errors when I run the script. But when I run from cmd prompt it is working fine.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

```
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> 

(\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:6:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

Please help...

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: _"Protractor 5 requires Node 6.9.4 or higher"_ you need an update somewhere

Comment: My node is version 9, with 6 also I got the same error. so upgraded to current version 9

Comment: perhaps a _webdriver-manager update_?

Comment: I have done that also

Comment: what do you  use to run it? might need to check configurations (and selected versions)

Comment: eclipse - neon 2

Comment: [Here is a thread](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/194) about your problem

Comment: eclipse - neon 2, Protractor - 5.2.0, node- 9, java - 1.8.0_31, selenium - 2.53 also tried for 3.6.0,

Answer (score 0):

If you i.e. used the Tern-Plugin , there is a built-in, but old version of node.js within this plugin.
Check your run-configuration, what node.js-version you addressed there.

In case this doesn't solve your issue yet, please post some details from your run-configuration, specifically from the tab "protractor" the details of node.js.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment you're using a built-in `node.js`-version.

1. Try to switch to "Native Node.js" and refer to `node.exe` of your local or global installation
2. Because tern-project has a problem with it, point 1. might not work. In that case, check [this SO-Question and especially @AngeloZerrs comment to its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249062/eclipse-unable-to-find-install-path-node-native) - it contains all infos needed
3. As option of last resort, you could copy the `node_modules` folder from your installation (containing protractor, etc.) into your eclipse workspace. **IMPORTANT**: add this folder to `.gitignore`, because this is environment, not code. Also this solution is a dirty hack. Replace it with Tern-Version 1.3 as soon as officially available OR remove Tern and switch to normal JavaScript project (might take a while until protractor runs again).

Comment: ${workspace_loc:/MVP_four/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js}; Start nose.js in only run mode; Node .js install : Node.js  4.2.5 - win32.x86_64

Comment: @rgurram28 based on your comment, I edited my answer. There should be a way for you now. Let me know, what worked for you.

Comment: those are my configurations in protractor tab. I am still facing the same issue. Please help me

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem for latest version NodeJS (and Protractor version) with eclipse compatibility issue by replacing the node.exe in Eclipse without selecting the "Native node.js" option.

After configuring your eclipse for protractor, you can find node.exe path in eclipse at:

```
Window>Preferences>AngularJS>Protractor (get node.js path from node.js field)
```

*In my case it was at: C:\Users\username\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse.......p2\pool\plugins\tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.0.201606160856\node-v4.2.4-win32-x86_64\node.exe"*

Replace with the latest node.exe from your machine that can be found at "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe".

Now your eclipse will run Protractor with the latest version of NodeJS and Protractor.